# Count multiple cell with multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I want specific count of cell based on the specific criteria. I am currently using COUNTIF formula to get the result.

```
=COUNTIF(J:J,A4)+COUNTIF(G:G,B2)+COUNTIF(H:H,D2)+COUNTIF(I:I,B3)
```

[image: img]

The actual result should be 2 in cell B4.

Comment: Could you give some more information? Is there something wrong with the method you're using? What are you trying to do? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in B4 then fill right and down.

```
=COUNTIFS($J:$J, $A4, $I:$I, B$3, INDEX($G:$H, 0, INT(COLUMN(B:B)/2)), INDEX($B$2:$E$2,1,(INT((COLUMN(A:A)-1)/2)*2)+1))
```

[image]

Comment: The above formula does work but if i change the value of H4 the result in cell B4 does not change. Also in G6 value change does not change the result in D5. Can you please check?